# How to run c program with .so file

Tags: c, gcc, go, shared-libraries, shared-objects

I have gone through all the solutions on StackOverflow as well as Ask Ubuntu.

I have a Go program:

```
package main

import "C"

//export Getint
func Getint() int {
        return  2
}

func main() {}
```

and I have generated `.so` file for the same with name `t.so and header file`t.h`

Now I would like to use this function in my C program.
I have written the code but I don't know how to execute it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <t.h>
int main()
{
int a;
a=Getint();
printf("number : %d",a);
return 0;
}
```

When I execute it with

```
gcc c.c t.so
```

it generates `a.out` file

but at the time of running `a.out` with `./a.out` it gives an error:

```
./a.out
Error while loading shared libraries: t.so: can not open shared object file: no such file or directory exists.
```

then I tried with:

```
gcc -c c.c -l t.so
```

So it generates `c.o` file and it is not executable.

Comment: all these files are in same location

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most probably your loader cannot find the library. Try to put the path to the directory where the libarry is located to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` prior to run your binary.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/my/library
./a.out
```

Comment: There are some concern in modifying "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/36048246/5595995.

Answer (score 11):

You should use the [linker option](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options) [`-rpath`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-runtime-library-search-path-230), which tells the linker to add information in the executable program where to find runtime libraries like your `.so` file.

This can be done using the GCC option `-Wl` which instructs the GCC frontend program to pass an option to the linker:

```
$ gcc c.c t.so -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)
```

This will pass `-rpath=$(pwd)` to the linker, and `$(pwd)` causes the shell to call the `pwd` command to return the current directory.

As long as you don't move the library the program should work.

---

You *can* use the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` too, but it's [not recommended](http://prefetch.net/articles/linkers.badldlibrary.html).

Answer (score 3):

.so files are shared object, meaning object that are available to all applications that need them.. that is, shared. Due to this characteristics, they need to be stored in a well known place. Also, they need to be indexed by the dynamic linker.

In linux for instance you typically have a file */etc/ld.so.conf* where all directories where shared object are automatically read from are stored

So your options are:

- Put your shared object file in a well known place
- Put your shared object file in a place of your choice and let the dynamic linker know about it: in linux you can modify *ld.so.conf* and run *ldconfig* to update ld indexes
- As other suggested write the path of your .so in the env variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH (since dynamic linker reads it before running your application). This must be done at each environment creation
- As other suggested use -rpath when compiling. Note that in this way you cannot move your .so file after the compilation

Personally I prefer installing the .so file in a system library path

Comment: Would you add information for "a well known place"?

Comment: As specified in the answer, a "well known place" is whatever directories are already indexed in the file /etc/ld.so.conf; usually `/usr/lib` is the general purpose path always included, but again.. check for your /etc/ld.so.conf. Note that you may have a directive in /etc/ld.so.conf to include all files present in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/; in this case open them one by one a find what path may better suit for you

Comment: Is there any drawback in modifyting "/etc/ld.so.conf" file? I found this, https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ldconfig.8.html,  and it sounds like manual editing not recommended.

Comment: I don't see any drawback if you know what you're doing and you are the only user who use your computer. Example scenario: you are working on a project1 for a shared library, and at the same time on a project2 which will use it. I would 
1) make prj1 output a file like `libprj1.so` in `target` dir
2) add in ld.so.conf absolute path of `target`
3) run # ldconfig after each recreation of `libprj1.so`
4) normally compile prj2 with `-l prj1` . If you change the lib, you don't need to recompile prj2 (but you need to call ldconfig each time)

Comment: In that scenario I believe you can also compile prj2 with `-L /absolute/path/to/target -l prj1`.. without modifying ld paths and ldconfig

Comment: @CloudCho what are your needs?

Comment: Thanks for sharing a case. I was looking for (manually) putting a generated SO file appropriate folder location, so I could call during executable file runtime (not compiling). 
    - Your "well known" place looks like a good choice, but there is no traceability
    - (Manually) modifying "/etc/ld.so.conf" sounds more risky.
    - LD_LIBRARY_PATH not recommanded (ref: "rpath vs. LD_LIBRARY_PATH" at https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html)
    - "rpath" is method during CPP code compiling not executable runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to let the dynamic linker find your shared library in the list. Syntax is similar to `PATH` a list of directories separted by `:`.

On OSX this environment variable is called `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.