# Why does setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH change the shared library dependencies?

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, ldd

I have a simple hello_world.cpp program. I compiled it using g++4.4.7 on a CentOS 6.6 system. When I look at `ldd a.out`:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffbd79e000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00002ab6f6819000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002ab6f6b1f000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00002ab6f6da4000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002ab6f6fba000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002ab6f65f7000)
```

When I load a module for gcc-4.9.2, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set to `/path/to/gcc-4.9.2/lib64` and running `ldd a.out` yields :

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff9393000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /path/to/gcc-4.9.2/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00002b2b7c104000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002b2b7c435000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /path/to/gcc-4.9.2/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00002b2b7c6b9000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b2b7c8cf000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002b2b7bee2000)
```

QUESTION : Why is the 4.9.2 version of the gcc libraries used when LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set, even though I compiled with with 4.4.7?

This seems to pose a problem of knowing which version of a library is being used. A user may compile a program with one compiler version, load a different compiler versions (via module) and then run the executable which uses a different library version than expected.

Comment: "When I load a module for gcc-4.9.2, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set to..." What do you mean? Who sets it to that?

Comment: it is set in the module file , i.e. : 
prepend-path LD_LIBRARY_PATH /path/to/gcc-4.9.2/lib64

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you're aware that the use of [Environment Modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_Modules_%28software%29)
is not a necessary or normal part of using GCC, or even using multiple versions of GCC.

Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to override the system dynamic linker's default directory search order
is a practice that has been long and loudly censured, for reasons that include the
one expressed in the last paragraph of your post. See e.g. [Gurus say that LD_LIBRARY_PATH is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/882110/1362568)

Doing so within environment modules in a system tailored for the use of multiple versions of tools or toolchains
can be regarded as a regulated application of a hazardous practice. In that context, however, the
setting of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your gcc-4.9.2 environment module is doing exactly what
such a setting is supposed to do: overriding the
dynamic linker's default directory search order. See [the documentation: 3.3.1](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html).

In principle it is possible that a program compiled and linked with an older or 
later version of GCC would behave unexpectedly if you choose to run it in the 
environment of the gcc-4.9.2 module. Environment modules are a niche convenience, 
and they come with this risk. Although if you built the program  in the native 
environment, or specifically in a module-enabled environment for gcc 4.4.7, then 
the risk attendant on running it in your gcc-4.9.2 environment is presumably one
that you don't have to take.