# How to point CMake to a different version of compiler and libstdc++

Tags: cmake

**Background:** Default `gcc` version on Debian Jessie `4.9.2` ***does not*** support `CXX_STANDARD 14`.

```
[dk@jessie /home/dk/qib]$ /usr/bin/gcc --version
gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10+deb8u1) 4.9.2
```

My [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/mortensorensen/QInteractiveBrokers/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L33) specifies `CXX_STANDARD 14` and `CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON`.

So I built `8.2.0` from source and installed in `/usr/local/bin/` location:

```
[dk@jessie /home/dk/qib]$ /usr/local/bin/gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 8.2.0
```

and pointed `cmake` to the newer compiler supporting that standard:

```
[dk@jessie /home/dk/qib/build]$ cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/g++ -DBUILD_x64=ON ..
```

---

**Problem:** The compiled binary then points to old `libstdc++.so.6` and I get this error:

```
[dk@jessie /home/dk/qib/build]$ ldd ../bin/qib.0.0.1.so
../bin/qib.0.0.1.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by ../bin/qib.0.0.1.so)
../bin/qib.0.0.1.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ../bin/qib.0.0.1.so)
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd43ee9000)                                                                                                              
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff532750000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff53244f000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff532239000)                                                                         
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff531e8e000)                                                                                 
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff532cdc000)
```

---

**One solution:**
One way of pointing the compiler/linker to the newer version using `cmake` is this (note that our binary now links to the newer `libstdc++.so.6.so`):

```
[dk@jessie /home/dk/qib/build]$ cmake -E env CXXFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib64/" cmake -DBUILD_x64=ON -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/g++ ..
...
[dk@jessie /home/dk/qib]$ ldd bin/qib.0.0.1.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd3533b000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f54340e0000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f5433ddf000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/local/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f5433bc8000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f543381d000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f54346e4000)
```

---

**Question**: Are there better, portable, distributable ways to automate the build, assuming (ideally) one cannot touch the original `CMakeLists.txt` (it's upstream) or use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` ([not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882110/gurus-say-that-ld-library-path-is-bad-whats-the-alternative) [advisable](https://gms.tf/ld_library_path-considered-harmful.html) [anyway](http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/_/ldpath.html))?

My draft `build.sh` script, as input to package manager such as `conda`:

```
[dk@jessie/home/dk/qib]$ cat build.sh                                                                                                                   #!/bin/bash

mkdir build && cd build            
cmake -E env CXXFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib64/" cmake -DBUILD_x64=ON -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/g++ ..
make
```

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to work as you are crosscompiling your project: just set up a toolchain file and prepare for build (Linux example):

```
mkdir -p build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=path/to/the/toolchain/file ..
```

Whenever you need to change the compiler or just some of the compile options you just need to change the toolchain file, without touching the CMakeLists.txt

You can find the reference [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE.html), but there are almost no information. A good tutorial is [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/CrossCompiling#the-toolchain-file).

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/31092052, `-H` and `-B` flags are undocumented because they shouldn't be used. The answer links to https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake-developers/2016-June/028843.html which says `"These are undocumented because they are internal options that
are not meant for public use"` and suggests `mkdir -p "$build" && pushd "$build" && cmake "$src" && popd` instead